# Swift facebook taggable_friends in uitable view

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, api, uitableview

I have been trying to load facebook `taggable_friends`, I was able to get them but can't load them in UItableView. I tried fetching request in the method "cell for Row at" but it changes the order or refresh every 2-3 seconds. I tried declaring arrays and store the names and profile pictures but I get a crash.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendCell", for: indexPath) as! friendstvc

    // The first try

    /*FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends?limit=5000", parameters: nil).start { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            cell.friendName.text = ""
            return
        }
        let dic = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        let data = dic["data"] as! NSArray
        if let name = dic["name"]
        {
            print(name as! String)
        }

        let valuedict = data[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        let id = valuedict["id"] as! String
        let name = valuedict["name"] as! String
        cell.friendName.text = name
        cell.profpic.profileID = id
    }*/

    // The second try
    cell.friendName.text = friendnames[indexPath.row] // crashes here
    cell.profpic.image = friendpictures[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

The below method is called in the viewDidLoad for the second try

```
// for the second try
func loadtaggableFriends()
{
// Called in the viewDidLoad
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends?limit=5000", parameters: nil).start { (connection, result, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        return
    }
    let dic = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    let data = dic["data"] as! NSArray
    if let name = dic["name"]
    {
        print(name as! String)
    }
    print(data.count)
    for i in 0...data.count - 1
    {
        let valuedict = data[i] as! Dictionary <String, Any>
        let name = valuedict["name"] as! String
        var dataurl: Data?
        if let picture = valuedict["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String
        {
            let loadurl = URL(string: url)
            dataurl = try? Data(contentsOf: loadurl!)
        }
        friendnames.append(name)
        friendpictures.append(UIImage(data: dataurl!)!)
    }
}
}
// declaring the arrays
var friendnames = [String]()
var friendpictures = [UIImage]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are using two array instead of two array use one array of dictionaries like : [[String:AnyObject]] .And way of using dictionary and inserting data into array is :

```
let dict = [String:AnyObject]() //create dictionary
    dict["friendpicture"] = "" //
    dict["friendnames"] = ""  //enter your data 
    arrOfDictionaries.append(dict) //insert data into array
```

Access data inside cellForRowAt method like this :

```
 let dict = arrOfDictionaries[indexPath.item]
    friendpicture = dict["friendpicture"] 
    friendnames   = dict["friendnames"]
```